# How to do mutation with word in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpu-word, mutation

I'm tryin to play with words. For example, I read word "script" from a txt file. Then would like to do all mutations of letters and write each of them.
So here are changes

```
 s=$
 s=5
 s=S
 s=s
 c=(
 c=[
 c={
 c=<
 c=c
 c=C
 r=r
 r=R
 i=i
 i=I
 i=|
 i=1
 i=!
 .
 .
 .
```

What i was thinking to get is

```
 scrypt
 $crypt
 5cript
 Scrypt
 s(ript
 $(cript
 .
 .
 .
```

So all possible combinations. Similar to itertool.product
I'm little confused how to do that. I started like this

```
 def main():

    with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f1, open('file2.txt', 'w') as f2:
       for word in f1:
           l=len(word)
           for i in range(l):
               if word[i] = s:
                   word1=word[i].raplace("$") #don't know if sintacs is ok
                   f2.write(word1)
               else: 
                   if word[i] = c:
                .
                .
```

Now I'm confused here. I would have to ask for every letter in alphabet and I'm complicating this.

I would probably need to have lots of loops inside loop. I think how many characters in word thats how manu for loops.

ITs to complicated and probably to slow. Is there some easy way? Some function (tool) to import?

Question is how to deal with to same letter in one word and how t

P.S I'm using python 3.4.2

Answer (score 1):

Construct a dictionary that maps each letter to its permitted replacements. Then use `itertools.product` to find all the combinations of those replacements.

```
import string
import itertools

replacements = """
s=$
s=5
s=S
c=(
c=[
c={
c=<
c=C
r=R
i=I
i=|
i=1
i=!
"""


d = {c:[c] for c in string.printable}
for line in replacements.strip().split("\n"):
    c, replacement = line.split("=")
    d[c].append(replacement)

word = "script"
for letters in itertools.product(*[d[c] for c in word]):
    print("".join(letters))
```

Result:

```
script
scrIpt
scr|pt
scr1pt
...
S(R1pt
S(R!pt
S[ript
S[rIpt
...
SCRIpt
SCR|pt
SCR1pt
SCR!pt
```

Comment: So I need replacements.txt and words.txt!! But what if words.txt have 2 words? Or I must put this after opening txt documents?

Comment: @Difermo I think it's easy to do that, just write the output to a file and read the replacements from a file.

Comment: i will try this and post if it works. It wil probably not but im learning :D. thx

Answer (score 0):

Ok I wrote code and try it. The first one i rune was this one

```
 import string
 import itertools
 def main():
      with open('mutation.txt', 'r') as l1, open('replacements.txt', 'r') as l2, open('mutator.txt', 'w') as l3:
         d = {c:[c] for c in string.printable}
         for line in replacements.strip().split("\n"):
             c, replacement = line.split("=")
             d[c].append(replacement)

         for word in l1:
             for letters in itertools.product(*[d[c] for c in word]):
                 l3.write("".join(letters))
      print("done")
if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

And it didn't worked. Problem was with repacements. It can not read or it must be written in another way.

The second time i tryed to put replacements like @Kevin did. And it worked just with lots of copys (duplicates). File of 38 bytes was 37.4MB. And after removing duplicates it went down to 1.27MB. So lots of duplicates. The code that worked and have duplicates was this one

```
 import string
 import itertools
 def main():
      replacements = """
      a=a
      a=A
      a=@
      a=4
      b=b
      b=B
      b=6
      c=c
      c=C
      c=<
      c={
      c=[
      d=d
      d=D
      e=e
      e=E
      e=3
      f=f
      f=F
      f=%
      f=8
      g=g
      g=G
      g=9
      h=h
      h=H
      h=#
      i=i
      i=I
      i=!
      i=1
      i=|
      j=j
      j=J
      j=]
      j=>
      j=}
      j=)
      k=k
      k=K
      l=l
      l=L
      l=!
      l=1
      l=|
      m=m
      m=M
      n=n
      n=N
      o=o
      o=O
      o=0
      p=p
      p=P
      r=r
      r=R
      s=s
      s=S
      s=$
      s=5
      t=t
      t=T
      t=+
      t=7
      u=u
      u=U
      v=v
      v=V
      z=z
      z=Z
      z=2
      """
      with open('mutation.txt', 'r') as l1, open('replacements.txt', 'r') as l2, open('mutator.txt', 'w') as l3:
         d = {c:[c] for c in string.printable}
         for line in replacements.strip().split("\n"):
             c, replacement = line.split("=")
             d[c].append(replacement)

         for word in l1:
             for letters in itertools.product(*[d[c] for c in word]):
                 l3.write("".join(letters))
      print("done")
if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

I notice that i didnt use l2 after open replacements.txt.
So I put this code

```
 for line in l2.strip().split("\n"):
```

run it without replacements in code (not @Kevin way) and it didnt work.
(it's the first code of this 2 i wrote). Then i use @kevin's way and put replacements inside code

So I'm fine to put replacements in code but how to solve duplicates?